# Chef: template 'name' from variable?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have an attribute in `attributes/default.rb`:

```
default["host_name"] = "domain.com"
```

And want to create NGINX's config with hostname from that attribute:

```
...
template "/etc/nginx/conf.d/#{@host_name}.conf" do
  source 'domain.conf.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
end
...
```

But during build - Chef can't see `host_name`:

```
 ...
 [14:18:28][Step 1/1] Recipe: nginx_proxy::default
 [14:18:28][Step 1/1]   * template[/etc/nginx/conf.d/.conf] action create
 [14:18:28][Step 1/1]     - create new file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.conf
 [14:18:28][Step 1/1]     - update content in file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.conf rom none to cc9a26
 ...
```

What's wrong here? Can it be achieved at all?

Chef docs don't say anything about "dynamic" `name` for `template`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `node` object to [access its attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html). What you are try to accessing with `@host_name` is a local variable.

The following should work:

```
template "/etc/nginx/conf.d/#{node['host_name']}.conf" do
  source 'domain.conf.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
end
```